# pixel width for a blank space

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

what is the pixel width of a character space ' ' in ubuntu.

Comment: Isn't that going to depend on your display settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of a character is not fixed as it may depends on font size, family, bold, etc.
Why do you need to know?

edit: you can get a string width with GTK using Pango layout: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2003-November/msg00071.html .

Comment: Ok Fine. If i maintain fixed font properties than how can i get it. I need to display text, so in calculating the text width space width is 0. because of that text width calculation becomes issue. And i need to display only specified length of text and truncate and replaced by "..."

Comment: I am using cairo method: I am getting width of each character so that i can remove width of others when length is more than some value and replace by "..."  int extents;           cr->get_text_extents(single_string,extents);